# jQuery appending classes to matched string/number combo

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to add classes to parts of a strung/number combination. What I mean by this is something like this:

```
myword22-30
```

`myword` would always be the same so it should match that directly, the numbers could be different and the hypen would always be there. I would like the outcome to be a final markup of something like:

```
<span class="word">myword</span><span class="num1">22</span><span class="divider">-</span><span class="num2">30</span>
```

Firstly is this possible? and is it efficient to do something like this with fairly large blocks of text in jQuery?

Comment: Can you be more precise? Is `myword22-30` a substring of a node? Or is it a whole node, like `<span>myword22-30</span>`?

Comment: so myword22-30 could be in a paragraph of text so <p>my paragraph myword22-30 is cool</p> should then be output as <p>my paragraph <span class="word">myword</span><span class="num1">22</span><span class="divider">-</span><span class="num2">30</span> is cool</p>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('p').html(function(idx, content){
    return content.replace(/myword\d+-\d+/g, function(text){
        var numcount = 0;
        return text.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+|\d+|-)/g, function(val){
            if(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(val)){
                return '<span class="word">' + val + '</span>';
            } else if(/[\d+]/.test(val)){
                return '<span class="num' + ++numcount + '">' + val + '</span>';
            } else {
                return '<span class="divider">' + val + '</span>';
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wBjJd/)

Comment: I'm guessing this would only work given the value of myword? What I would like to do is find each occurrence within say a div and then add the classes.

Comment: Would there be a way to separate out the numbers part so instead of having a count that determines the class there are two separate if statements for it? I'm thinking of the use case of someone wanting different tags for num1 and num2 e.g. one a span one a div. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: That gives different classes, which is awesome but would there be a way of doing it with different tags?

Comment: so instead of span you want to use another tag

Comment: potentially two different tags,so the first nuber might be in a span but the second might be in a p - if that makes sense?

Comment: @user319940 you can apply the same login again http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wBjJd/5/

Comment: is there any way of using a forward slash instead of the hyphen? I tried escaping it, so \/ but it caused it not to match.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean ?

```
var $newClass = $(".word").text() + $(".num1").text() + '-' + $(".num2").text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pgbqg/

then you can add this class by using

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I'm not so sure, to summarise I want to find this (in say a paragraph): myword22-30 where myword is always the same but either number could be different, and output <span class="word">myword</span><span class="num1">22</span><span class="divider">-</span><span class="num2">30</span> within the HTML